# Jenkins groovy pipeline using try catch and variable from python exit

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, try-catch

I have a pipeline on jenkins that inside a stage it uses the try-catch framework to try to run a python script. once run, the python script either prints a good value or prints a bad value and exits, depending on the input. My goal is to later use this to make a test, so my requirement is that I need to be able to diferentiate if the python script succeeded or if it was terminated with exit('ERR_MESSAGE').

I have made it work if python runs to the end. However, if python ends with the exit command, the jenkinsfile correctly understands that and it follows to catch, but it does not store the text printed by the python script before, as I need.

Can you help? What am I doing wrong? Please see below the jenkinsfile stage

```
stage('Test branch') {
            steps {
                script {
                    test_results = 'position 1'
                    try {
                        test_results = sh (
                            script: "python3 \${WORKSPACE}/testingjenkinsexit.py notpass",
                            returnStdout: true
                        ).trim()
                        echo "Test results in passed test: ${test_results}"
                    } catch (err) {
                        echo "Test results in failed test numb 1: " + test_results
                        echo "Test results in failed test numb 2: ${test_results}"
                        echo err.getMessage()
                        println err.dump()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

in the code abve, I am calling the script 'testingjenkinsexit.py' with input'notpass', as this is the one when the python script will terminate with exit. If I use input pass, then it works correctly as python does not end with exit.

and the python script below

```
from sys        import argv

def testingjenkins(desired_output):

    #print relevant test results. If at least one test failed, stop execution
    if desired_output == "'pass'":
        print(desired_output)
    else:
        print('tests did not pass')
        exit('Deployement interrupted by python.')

desired_output = "'" + str(argv[1]) + "'"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    testingjenkins(desired_output)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

I used try - catch within the jenkinsfile to call a python script that prints values and might terminate with exit('MESSAGE') if input is bad. I was expecting that the try-catch would be able to deal with the python ending with exit (what it does with success) and I was expecting that in both good execution and bad execution (that ends with exit) the try-catch would be able to store the messages printed by the python script (what it does not do).

Comment: The output of the execution above is:
deployment interrupted by python
tests did not pass
Test results in failed test numb 1: position 1
Test results in failed test numb 2: position 1
scripts returned exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior I suppose. When the script exits with a non-zero exit code the StandardOut will not be returned. If you want to get the output irrespective of the status you can do something like this. The following will combine both STDOUT and STDERR and return while exiting the script with exit code `0`. This will not move the execution to the `catch` block. So you will have to add a condition and check the returned message.

```
test_results = sh (
                  script: "python3 \${WORKSPACE}/test.py notpass 2>&1 || echo \"status:\$?\"; exit 0",
                  returnStdout: true
              )

# Output
Test results in passed test: tests did not pass
Deployement interrupted by python.
status:1
```

Another approach is to write the STDOUT to a file and read that in the `catch` block.

```
stage('Test branch') {
    steps {
        script {
            test_results = 'position 1'
            try {
                test_results = sh (
                    script: "python3 \${WORKSPACE}/test.py notpass > output",
                    returnStdout: true
                )
                echo "Test results in passed test: ${test_results}"
            } catch (err) {
                output = readFile(file: 'output')
                echo "Test results in failed test numb 1: " + output
                echo "Test results in failed test numb 2: ${test_results}"
                echo err.getMessage()
                println err.dump()
            }
        }
    }
}
```